# .net generic bugs?

Tags: .net, generics, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I found for me a strange behabiuor for generic and overloading method. It seems that 
with generics the overloading mechanism doesn't work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestGeneric1
{
    class Program
    {
        class B
        {
            public void f()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("B.f() called!");
            }
        }

        class D : B
        {
            public void g()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("D.g() called!");
            }
        }

        class H
        {
            public static void over(B b)
            {
                b.f();
            }

            public static void over(D d)
            {
                d.g();
            }
        }

        class Gen<T> where T : B
        {
            T _item;

            public Gen(T item)
            {
                _item = item;
            }


            public void test()
            {
                H.over(_item);
            }
        }

        class Gen2
        {
            public static void test<T>(T item) where T : B
            {
                H.over(item);
            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            B b = new B();
            D d = new D();

            Console.WriteLine("Direct Call");
            H.over(b); // OK!
            H.over(d); // OK;

            Console.WriteLine("Call via Generics");
            Gen<B> testGenB = new Gen<B>(b);
            Gen<D> testGenD = new Gen<D>(d);
            testGenB.test(); // OK 
            testGenD.test(); // Wrong !!!

            Console.WriteLine("Call via Generics 2 chance...");
            Gen2.test<B>(b); // OK !
            Gen2.test<D>(d); // wrong
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any body that can explain this?
Is there a workaround.

What i try to do is to realize a generic visitor class (visitor pattern) with generic.
TIA

Added:

The question I really try to resolve is the problem of double dispatch. 
Suppose you want write a little game engine where you have to handle collision between
sprite:

```
interface ISprite
{
    void Hit(ISprite sprite);
}

abstract class Sprite : ISprite
{
    public void Hit(ISprite sprite)
    {
        Hit(sprite as Sprite);
    }

}

class SpriteA : Sprite
{
}

class SpriteB : Sprite
{
}
```

what I do is to implement the visitor pattern in this way

```
interface IVisitorSprite
{
    void Visit(SpriteA item);
    void Visit(SpriteB item);
}


abstract class Sprite : ISprite
{

    protected abstract void Accept(IVisitorSprite visitor);

}

class SpriteA : Sprite
{
    protected override void Accept(IVisitorSprite visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

class SpriteB : Sprite
{
    protected override void Accept(IVisitorSprite visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }

}
```

the hit method call the visit pattern twice:

```
abstract class Sprite : ISprite
{
    public void Hit(ISprite sprite)
    {
        Hit(sprite as Sprite);
    }

public void Hit(Sprite sprite)
{
    HitResoverBuilder hitBuilder = new HitResoverBuilder();
    Accept(hitBuilder);
    sprite.Accept(hitBuilder.HitResolver);
}

protected abstract void Accept(IVisitorSprite visitor);


}
class HitResoverBuilder : IVisitorSprite
{
    public IVisitorSprite HitResolver { get; private set; }

    void IVisitorSprite.Visit(SpriteA item)
{
       HitResolver = new HitResolver<Penguin>(item);
}

void IVisitorSprite.Visit(SpriteB item)
    {
    HitResolver = new HitResolver<Flame>(item);
}
}

class HitResolver<T> : IVisitorSprite 
{
    public HitResolver(T spriteOne)
    {
    _spriteOne = spriteOne;
    }

    T _spriteOne;

void IVisitorSprite.Visit(SpriteA item)
    {
        HitHelper.Hit(_spriteOne, item);
    }

void IVisitorSprite.Visit(SpriteB item)
    {
        HitHelper.Hit(_spriteOne, item);
    }
}

class HitHelper
{
    public static void Hit(SpriteA a, SpriteB b)
    {
        // manage hit between spriteA and SpriteB
    }

    public static void Hit(SpriteB b, SpriteA a)
    {
        Hit(a,b);
    }

    public static void Hit(SpriteB b, SpriteB b1)
    {
        // manage hit between 2  SpriteB
    }

    public static void Hit(SpriteA a, SpriteA a1)
    {
        // manage hit between 2  SpriteA
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" and "wrong"? What behaviour did you expect, and what behaviour did you see?

Comment: You should include the output. I can guess at what the problem is but can't be sure.

Comment: Change class D.g to "override f" and make B.f virtual and it will work as expected. Oh and H.over(D) call needs to change to d.f().

Comment: The visitor pattern's usually implemented using double dispatch (overloading and virtual methods).  There's a reasonable sample on wikipedia, although the code's in java, it's essentially the same.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Comment: first of all, thanks for all.  I add some code to the question.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you're seeing everything using the generics treated as if it were an instance of B (which is what I would expect).

You constrain the generic type `T` to be `B`. That means that whatever type you use for your generic parameter, it will be treated as an instance of `B` when determining which overload to call at compile time. That means that when `H.over()` is called, it uses the overload that takes an instance of `B`.

If you're trying to implement the Visitor Pattern using generics, then you need to properly set up your class structure (properly overloading methods is key):

```
class B
{
    public virtual void f() { Console.WriteLine("B.f() called!"); }
}

class D : B
{
    public override void f() { g(); }

    public void g() { Console.WriteLine("D.g() called!"); }
}

static class H
{
    public static void over(B b){ b.f(); }
}
```

Comment: Thats true because it is decided at **compile time** if `H.over(D d)` or `H.over(B b)` is called. The compiler only knows that `T` is a subtype of `B` and chooses the second overload because it cannot know that in your case the overload taking a `D` would be more appropriate at **runtime**. Absolutely correct behavior.

Comment: Your answer talks about using generics, but your code sample doesn't use them.  Also, I don't see how your solution actually H (which I'm assuming is the visitor) allows the behaviour to be changed for different node types.  It can only ever access the public interface of the base class (B), not being able to treat the nodes differently, which I thought was one of the main reasons for the pattern.

Comment: In your code sample, you've got B deriving from D.  It should be D deriving from B (it won't let me edit it for you, because it's less than a 6 character change)

Comment: @forsvarir - That's because, with the code I have written, the OPs code that actually uses generics wouldn't need to change.

Comment: Aaaaaaahhhhhhh... At least I understand your point now, although I still fail to see what having a generic would actually add, or how H is substitutable, but I think that's more to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: rewrite answer after various changes to question

As has already been said (see Justin), you can't just use generics, because the compiler needs to know at compile time what the supported types of object are.  It's also still not clear what you're trying to achieve by using generics.  If it's to save typing, then this probably isn't a solution to your problem...

That said, I think your problem is you have two sprites of unknown type (possibly from a collection or something):

```
Sprite a; // may be SpriteA, may be SpriteB
Sprite b; // may be SpriteA, may be SpriteB
```

You want to orchestrate the collision between the two sprites, but in order to do so you need to know the types of both sprites so that you can call the appropriate function on your HitHelper:

```
public static void Hit(SpriteA a, SpriteB b)
```

For this to work, you need to identify the types of sprite1 and sprite2, which you've attempted to do using the visitor pattern and it didn't work.  This is because you can only resolve one parameter at a time (you can identify a, or b, but not both at once).  Consequently, you have to double dispatch twice (once for each variable) so that you can resolve both parameters.

An example of how to do this is shown below (there may well be a better approach, suggestions welcome).

```
// Define some SpriteTypes, that support an Invoke/visit method

abstract class Sprite  {
    public abstract TResult Invoke<TResult>(ISpriteInvoker<TResult> invoker);
}

class SpriteA : Sprite {
    public override TResult Invoke<TResult> (ISpriteInvoker<TResult> invoker){
        return invoker.Invoke(this);
    }
}

class SpriteB : Sprite {
    public override TResult Invoke<TResult> (ISpriteInvoker<TResult> invoker){
        return invoker.Invoke(this);
    }
}

// Define Invoker / visit interface
// Has to return a result to support the way it's used later (far from ideal
// it would be nice if there was a way to pass 'void' as the result)
interface ISpriteInvoker<TResult>{
    // note, one invoke overload for each type of supported sprite
    TResult Invoke(SpriteA sprite);
    TResult Invoke(SpriteB sprite);
}


// Define interface for hitter

interface IHitter {
    // Note, one overload for each type of sprite that can be hit
    int Hit(SpriteA sprite);
    int Hit(SpriteB sprite);
}

// Define some Hitter classes (one for each type of sprite that
// can do the hitting).  It would be nice if this could be
// Hitter<TSprite>, however as previously stated, this won't work
// because the compiler doesn't support where TSprite : (SpriteA or SpriteB)
// at least not that I can find..

class SpriteAHitter : IHitter {
    SpriteA _sprite;

    public SpriteAHitter(SpriteA sprite) {
        _sprite = sprite;
    }

    public int  Hit(SpriteA sprite)
    {
        HitHelper.Hit(_sprite, sprite);
        return 0;
    }

    public int  Hit(SpriteB sprite)
    {
        HitHelper.Hit(_sprite, sprite);
        return 0;
    }

}

class SpriteBHitter : IHitter {
    SpriteB _sprite;

    public SpriteBHitter(SpriteB sprite) {
        _sprite = sprite;
    }

    public int  Hit(SpriteA sprite)
    {
        HitHelper.Hit(_sprite, sprite);
        return 0;
    }

    public int  Hit(SpriteB sprite)
    {
        HitHelper.Hit(_sprite, sprite);
        return 0;
    }

}

// Invoker that takes in a sprite and creates
// the appropriate Hitter wrapper.

class HitterCreator : ISpriteInvoker<IHitter> {
    public IHitter Invoke(SpriteA sprite) {
        return new SpriteAHitter(sprite);
    }

    public IHitter Invoke(SpriteB sprite) {
        return new SpriteBHitter(sprite);
    }
}

// Invoker that is constructed with a hitter
// and uses it to kick off the appropriate collison

class HitActioner : ISpriteInvoker<int> {
    IHitter _hitter;

    public HitActioner(IHitter hitter) {
        _hitter = hitter;
    }

    public int Invoke(SpriteA sprite) {
        return _hitter.Hit(sprite);
    }

    public int Invoke(SpriteB sprite) {
        return _hitter.Hit(sprite);
    }
}


// Class taken from question, processes the hits
// currently just outputs what hit what...

class HitHelper {
    public static void Hit(SpriteA a, SpriteB b) {
        Console.WriteLine("a hit b");
    }

    public static void Hit(SpriteB b, SpriteA a) {
        Console.WriteLine("b hit a");
    }

    public static void Hit(SpriteB b, SpriteB b1) {
        Console.WriteLine("b hit b1");
    }
    public static void Hit(SpriteA a, SpriteA a1) {
        Console.WriteLine("a hit a1");
    }
}


class Program {
    // class for testing two members
    class Collision {
        public Sprite Hitter { get; set; } // sprite causing collision
        public Sprite Receiver { get; set; } // sprite getting hit
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // Define each type of collision (A->A, A->B, B->A, B->B)
        Collision[] collisions = new Collision[] { 
            new Collision{Hitter=new SpriteA(), Receiver = new SpriteA()} ,
            new Collision{Hitter=new SpriteA(), Receiver = new SpriteB()} ,
            new Collision{Hitter=new SpriteB(), Receiver = new SpriteA()} ,
            new Collision{Hitter=new SpriteB(), Receiver = new SpriteB()} };

        // For each scenario, process the collision
        foreach (var collision in collisions) {
            // Create the appropriate hitter wrapper for the sprite doing the hit
            var hitter = collision.Hitter.Invoke(new HitterCreator());

            // perform the collision action against the object that has been hit
            var result = collision.Receiver.Invoke(new HitActioner(hitter));
        }

        // Output:
        // a hit a1
        // a hit b
        // b hit a
        // b hit b1
    }

}
```